# Can you max both Paragon and Renegade points?

Tags: mass-effect-series

Mass Effect's morality system handles "Good" vs. "Evil" in terms of two independent ratings of "Paragon" and "Renegade".  It is very possible for a hero who is primarily Paragon to also have earned some Renegade points along the way, though this does not typically detract from his Paragon score.

However, there are (with the exception of some bugs) a finite number of opportunities to increase your score in either of these aspects.  Also, a choice to increase one usually means passing up a potential increase of the other.

So, this leaves me wondering out of curiosity:  Are there enough morality-based decisions in each game for a player to max out *both* Paragon and Renegade scales on the same character?  If so, do the game mechanics really allow for this?

Comment: In which game? It's certainly not possible in ME3 when both are part of a greater scale and paragon/renegade become a zero sum game

Comment: @BenBrocka As the question says, "in each game".  I would like answers that cover all three.  I know the mechanics are not necessarily the same in each game, but I think this is a narrow enough topic that all three games can be reasonably covered in one answer post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are ways to max both paragon and renegade in ME1 and ME2 if you use the glitches described on the [wiki page](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Morality#Infinite_Paragon.2FRenegade_Points_Exploit).

> On Noveria. You are given a side mission leading you to speak to Lorik Qui'in, a turian, at the bar. A mission progression choice enables you to encourage him to testify in a court case. You can choose from either a Paragon or Renegade dialogue option if you have at least 5 points in charm and/or intimidate. Choosing either of these options will give you a reward of 24 Paragon or 25 Renegade points respectively. The conversation will end but you can talk to him again. Ask about a different topic (i.e. Matriarch Benezia), then choose "Another question". The option to convince him to testify will reappear. Repeat this for infinite Paragon and/or Renegade points. This bug appears to exist across all 3 platforms (Xbox360, PS3, PC). This bug still exists in Mass Effect Legendary Edition.

There are multiple ways to do so in both games.  In ME1, you can also legitimately gain the paragon/renegade skill ranks as your skills carry over in a new game+ and there are points in the story where you automatically rank up in those skills.

Outside of exploits, its impossible to max both paragon and renegade in ME2 or 3, but you can max the skills in ME1 via new game +.

Currently, there are no known ways to max both in ME3, but it becomes less necessary as in ME3 your total rep can contribute to speech unlock checks rather than individual levels.